# Getting EPS vector as georeferenced layer into QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, georeferencing

I have an eps-file with polygons of landuse. The file has coordinates to georeference it. I need to convert it into a geo vector.

[image: eps-vector with landuse but without georeference]

I could do the following steps:

1. export/convert the eps to raster (unsing [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/de/))
2. georeference it with GDAL or [J Rectifier](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/J_Rectifier/) (great tool!)
3. reclassify it (using [r.reclass](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.reclass.html) from GRASS) and
4. vectorize it with GDAL, GRASS or SAGA.

but is there another way without rasterizing the eps-vector?

Comment: Coordinates are only a text inside the file or they are associated to the polygons? In any case you can convert the file from eps to shape (it's possibile with illustrator and a plugin and maybe with other sw). If the shape has no coordinates you can move all the polygons to the correct place.

Comment: The coordinates are just a text inside. I tried to convert via Inkscape (I don't use/have illustrator) to DXF and imported it to QGIS. Its working, but the result is without the colors (of course) so finally I think, I need to go the raster-way.

Comment: I don't know how many classes have you got, But you can select them by color inside inkscape and export only selection. After that, inside Qgis, merge all the polygons. In this way you will "save" colors.

Comment: Thats a good idea!